# How to add remote submodule to my github project?

Tags: git, github

For example:

[image]

How do they do it?

I tried next but it just downloaded module locally (didn't appear on github):

```
git submodule add https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg
git submodule update --init --recursive
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### I tried next but it just downloaded module locally (didn't appear on github)

> ```
> git submodule add https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg
> ```

You are missing a parameter - the path where the submodule repository will be added to the main repository.

Try:

```
git submodule add https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg FFmpeg
```

---

#### Further Reading

- [Working with submodules | The GitHub Blog](https://blog.github.com/2016-02-01-working-with-submodules/)
- [Git Submodules: Adding, Using, Removing, Updating :: Chris Jean](https://chrisjean.com/git-submodules-adding-using-removing-and-updating/)